Is there a general guideline for how much to put in annuities?
A google search, and the wonderful AI that answers questions now, 20%-40% is the answer that spits out, which is - generally about what I think.  But 20%-40% is a fairly broad range.
I'm talking about investing now (about 60 years of age), for a yearly dividend starting at retirement age for the rest of your life say, 68 or 70?   Not 100% decided on retirement age and when to start collecting.
It's fairly obvious that if somebody expects to live a long time, say, has ancestors who lived into their 90s or 100s, then annuities make sense.    If a person is in poor health at 60, they make very little sense.
There's also the safety argument.    Though the market has outperformed annuities, at least since the big crash in 2008, there's no guarantee that will continue.    Diversity is good, safety is good too, and getting a guaranteed return for the rest of one's life is a safe investment - IMHO.
The downside, is money put into an annuity is no longer there for people you wish to leave your estate to.
So, painting a general picture - a person who expects to live at least to 85, no kids and scared of the market, 40% feels closer to my ideal than 20%.     But I'm curious if there's any overall guidelines or formulas that one can use for this kind of thing.
Are annuities generally considered a sound part of a retirement plan?
Thanks.

this calls for opinions and speculations. There are many factors involved from personal financial situation to potential tax benefits, and there's no "general guideline". In fact, one might argue against annuities at all.

In most cases Annuities are a bad idea for retirement investing.

@littleadv  That's why I asked for a general guideline, not specific opinions.

@JohnFx   Why is that?   Certainly, if somebody lives to 100, it's a very good investment.   I've heard other retirement ideas, like "live off 4% of your savings".     I don't understand why an annuity is a "bad idea".  It seems like a good safety mechanism for a share of one's savings?    I'd be interested in knowing why you believe that.

The fees are notoriously high, that's why brokers always push them hard. It is basically insurance against living beyond your money, but it comes at a high cost.

Not all annuities are unreasonably priced, assuming that you are using them for their intended purpose, which is to pay somebody else to take some of the investment risk. Like any insurance product, whether it is worth buying depends on the specific offering and your specific needs.  You should also consider charitable remainder funds and charitable gift annuities, if your income will be high enough that the tax savings are worthwhile.

When you're talking about annuities, it is really helpful to specify what type of annuity you're talking about.  When you retire, taking some of your savings to buy an immediate annuity is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.  Putting money into other types of annuities before retirement is very seldom a good idea.  Particularly if you aren't maxing out all of your tax-advantaged retirement accounts.

@JustinCave and 0xFEE1DEAD   Thank you for the info.    I did have a specific type of annuity in mind, but not knowing the specific terms makes it harder to ask the question.   Maybe this gets closed and I can re-ask the question in a better way.
JohnFX, Yes, high fees are a concern, but there is a provided safety net as well.   Safety is important too.    I appreciate your comment as well.

There are many different kinds of annuities So it would be helpful if you specified what you were looking for. FWIW, Some Step-up annuities can be duplicated by the investor, avoiding the high fees and obtaining more downside protection and more potential income.

The best advice is to put zero in annuities.  A scam much like whole life.
